# Obtener el maximo de una DB dada dos condiciones

Tags: mysql

Tengo el siguiente problema tengo una **DB** con diversos campos como muestro en la imagen. lo que necesito realizar es encontrar el máximo de remisión pero que sea de una sola empresa por ejemplo el **máximo** de todas las **emp1** o el **máximo** de todas las **emp2** con sentencias de `MySQL`. probe con la siguiente sentencia pero no me funciona.

```php
$query2 = "SELECT  remision  FROM equipos WHERE ( SELECT MAX(remision) AND empresa='emp1')";
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ese where obviamente esta mal... el where es campo = condicion.. mas alla de eso, si queres el max de una sola empresa, porque no usaste la consulta de adentro solametne... esa no te andubo?????

Comment: El max de una sola empresa, ¿no te funciona?: `SELECT MAX(remision) remision FROM equipos WHERE empresa='emp1'`

Comment: modifique el código a como me lo recomendaron. $query2 = "SELECT   MAX(remision) remision FROM equipos WHERE empresa='emp1'";. pero cuando ejecuto el print_r($extraido2['remision']); me sale vacío

Comment: Quizás si compartes los inserts o un csv o un dump con tus datos de ejemplo para insertar en una base te podemos ayudar mejor. La consulta `SELECT MAX(remision) remision FROM equipos WHERE empresa='emp1'` está rara, eso de que `remision` aparece dos veces en el where, creo qeu la segunda no va y quedaría como en mi respuesta. Si aún así no te devuelve resultados, puede ser que la columna empresa tenga algún espacio en esos registros que no se puede ver en una imagen.

Answer (score 3):

Creo que esto debería funcionar:

```sql
select empresa, max(remision) 
from equipos
group by empresa;
```

Esto daría el máximo por empresa, ahora si se quiere para una empresa dada:

```sql
select max(remision)
from equipos 
where empresa = 'emp1';
```

Comment: Una pregunta, pero aquí como condiciono que empresa es porque manejo en mi ejemplo varias empresas diferentes y cada una lleva sus números de remisiones independientes de las otras